# How to return true if one number(asked by program) is positive and the other one(also asked by program) is negative

Tags: c#, console-application

So i got this assignment that I should write a c# program that lets the user type in two numbers. The program should then return true if one of the inputs is positive and the other one negative. I've tried the following but I don't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
static void check()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type in a positive number:");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Type in a negative number:");
        int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (num1 > 0; num2 < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct input.");
        }       
        else()
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Wrong input.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to use the `&` operator. `if (num1 > 0 & num2 < 0)`. [read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: Do you need to check other numbers apart from integers?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to a solution. If you change:

```
if (num1 > 0; num2 < 0)
```

into this:

```
if (num1 > 0 && num2 < 0)
```

And remove the "()" after your else statement you will get your desired result. The semicolon assumed that it is the end of a sequence. I would recommend you to look at boolean operators to find out more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a logical and operator (i.e., `&&`) between the two conditions. Additionally, there should be no parentheses (`()`) after the `else`:

```cs
if (num1 > 0 && num2 < 0) // Note the usage of &&
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct input.");
}       
else // () removed here
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AND operator sytnax in C# is '&&' so in the line of code you should replace ';' with '&&':

```
 if (num1 > 0 && num2 < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct input.");
        }
```

You also need to remove the parentheses after else since it does not denote any arguments

```
if (*condition*)
{
}
else
{
}
```

N.B. if you where using an OR comparator you would use ||